# PHP - Rearrange multi-dimensional array to value become key

Tags: php, arrays

Using this PHP code:

```
 function parseCSV($csvfile) {
        $csv = array();
        $rowcount = 0;
        if (($handle = fopen($csvfile, "r")) !== FALSE) {
            $max_line_length = defined('MAX_LINE_LENGTH') ? MAX_LINE_LENGTH : 10000;
            $header = fgetcsv($handle, $max_line_length);
            $header_colcount = count($header);
            while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, $max_line_length)) !== FALSE) {
                $row_colcount = count($row);
                if ($row_colcount == $header_colcount) {
                    $entry = array_combine($header, $row);
                    $csv[] = $entry;
                }
                else {
                    error_log("csvreader: Invalid number of columns at line " . ($rowcount + 2) . " (row " . ($rowcount + 1) . "). Expected=$header_colcount Got=$row_colcount");
                    return null;
                }
                $rowcount++;
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
        else {
            error_log("csvreader: Could not read CSV \"$csvfile\"");
            return null;
        }

        return $csv;
    }
```

to parse CSV and get this values what is realy good:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["keyword"]=>
    string(7) "TEST"
    ["tag1"]=>
    string(5) "TEST1"
    ["tag2"]=>
    string(5) "TEST2"
    ["tag3"]=>
    string(5) "TEST3"
    ["tag4"]=>
    string(5) "TEST4"
    ["tag5"]=>
    string(5) "TEST5"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["keyword"]=>
    string(9) "BadCredit"
    ["tag1"]=>
    string(7) "Credit1"
    ["tag2"]=>
    string(7) "Credit2"
    ["tag3"]=>
    string(7) "Credit3"
    ["tag4"]=>
    string(7) "Credit4"
    ["tag5"]=>
    string(7) "Credit5"
  }
}
```

Now I need in second part of my code to reorder that value to loook like this:

```
array(2) {
  ["TEST"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["tag1"]=>
    string(5) "TEST1"
    ["tag2"]=>
    string(5) "TEST2"
    ["tag3"]=>
    string(5) "TEST3"
    ["tag4"]=>
    string(5) "TEST4"
    ["tag5"]=>
    string(5) "TEST5"
  }
  ["BadCredit"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["tag1"]=>
    string(7) "Credit1"
    ["tag2"]=>
    string(7) "Credit2"
    ["tag3"]=>
    string(7) "Credit3"
    ["tag4"]=>
    string(7) "Credit4"
    ["tag5"]=>
    string(7) "Credit5"
  }
}
```

I need to get "keyword" value and place like key for array to lather can made objects for other part of code. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) function:

```
// $array with values

$newArray = array_reduce($array, function($carry, $item) {
    $keyword = $item['keyword'];
    unset($item['keyword']);
    $carry[$keyword] = $item;
    return $carry;
}, array());
```

For example try code below:

```
// sample code

$array = array(
  array(
      "keyword"=> "TEST",
      "tag1"=>"TEST1"
  ),
  array(
      "keyword" => "BadCredit",
        "tag1"=> "Credit1"
    )
);


$newArray = array_reduce($array, function($carry, $item) {
    $keyword = $item['keyword'];
    unset($item['keyword']);
    $carry[$keyword] = $item;
    return $carry;
}, array());
```

Output will be:

```
array(2) {
  ["TEST"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["tag1"]=>
    string(5) "TEST1"
  }
  ["BadCredit"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["tag1"]=>
    string(7) "Credit1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Good point. That is almost right solution but is not good. That's where I stack, I get similar solution but look above in my question how need to look. I need keyword values to become keys.

Comment: ok, I should be more careful:) Just use `array_reduce` instead of `array_map`

Comment: Thanks Man, that's it. I totaly was lost!

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
foreach ($csv as $item) {
    $new_array[$item['keyword']] = array_diff_key($item, ['keyword' => 0]);
}
```

`array_diff_key` will remove the keyword from each element before appending it to the new array using `keyword` as key.

Comment: You're welcome. I think there's usually more than one way to do things. :)

Comment: Totaly, I will use your solution because is cleaner.